# How do I complete Jimmy's sidequest?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Jimmy's quest for a flute sends you to talk to the Rancher. I can't find the key to the barn in the north, by Canada. Is that where I'm supposed to go, and where can I find the key? I've looked all over!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must set Jimmy as your active buddy and then head to the farm. If Jimmy is your active buddy, the Rancher will be there, and after some dialogue he'll give you the key to the barn.

Unless you can soak a lot of damage or have the means to take out a couple enemies in a single turn, I highly recommend keeping Jimmy as your buddy for the fight in the barn, as his ability to put enemies to sleep is highly useful in against the group inside.

After that, just climb the ladder and retrieve the flute from a chest on the upper level.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of that! I'll give you an upvote as well when I hit 15 rep.

Comment: I got mine off just before him too but his is more detailed lol

Comment: Can you only beat this quest before you finish the main story? I have beaten the main story but trying to back track and finish the side quests and I can’t trigger the farmer scene with jimmy as a partner

Answer (score 6):

In order to complete this quest you need to go to the barn area with Jimmy as your current partner. This took me a while also do not feel bad.